# Add raster value to features AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_RASTER'?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga

When I try to run the "add raster value to features" (available into SAGA Tools), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/AlgorithmDialog.py", line 249, in accept
    msg = self.alg._checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting()
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 239, in _checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting
    return self.checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting()
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithm.py", line 343, in checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting
    param.datatype == dataobjects.TYPE_RASTER):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_RASTER'
```

I'm using QGIS 2.18.10 and Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04

I don't have any clue to solve this error.

Comment: which version of saga is installed?

Comment: I came across the same problem. Same QGIS version, same Ubuntu and I have saga 2.3.1

Comment: @johanvdw I have installed saga 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue in QGIS: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16920

Comment: Should be fixed now.