# QGIS-SAGA Add Raster Values To Points How to apply update

Tags: qgis, raster, saga

I have a lattice of points.  I have a surface model.  Both layers share a CRS.  I am trying to populate the point file with the values from the underlying raster using the SAGA tool Add Raster Values to Points in QGIS 2.18 (64bit).  The tool fails with the following message 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_RASTER' See log for more details.

I am new to QGIS but not GIS software.

I do not understand why this operation would fail.  I do not understand the error message.

How do I populate my point file with values from the raster?

---

I see that this is a known bug and there is a fix [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/4915) but how do I apply the update/fix?

Comment: seems to be a known issue, see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/245914/55203) which relates to a similar algorithm (add raster values to features). As a workaround, the **point sampling tool** plugin is worth a go

Comment: Thanks, @Steven Kay, the point sampling tool plugin did the trick here but I would still like to get the SAGA tool working.